# What is the Server name for SQL Server2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have sucessfully installed the Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express
from the following link:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593
file name: SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe

When I opend the MS SQL Server Management Studio, it asks for the Server Name which I am not sure what it is nor the login name and password.

Can someone please explain?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server name (and instance name) for SQL Server Express by default would be `localhost\sqlexpress` (or `.\sqlexpress`, or `yourMachineName\sqlexpress`, or `x.x.x.x\sqlexpress`, where `x.x.x.x` is your machine's IP address).  That is provided two things:

1. You on the machine that houses the database engine
2. You kept the defaults for SQL Server Express installation to make it a named instance, named `SQLEXPRESS`

As for the login.  Most likely if you just installed it, select Windows Authentication and try to connect.  I'm guessing you have added your account as SA priv.  Did you create an `sa` account during installation?  If so, and you enabled Mixed Mode authentication then you can log in with the `sa` credentials you created initially.

Comment: Thanks Shark! Here is the instruction from this youtube link wich i got confused at 4:49 (when the server name was entered) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7whqA-VZaYc

Comment: @HungCaptain That guy just had a default instance, which is why it looked like he only typed in the server name.  For the default instance, you connect with just the server name.  For a named instance, it is the `servername\instancename`.

Comment: thanks once again. I am not very good at this. So what exactly did he entered in the server name, login info, and password? Sorry for asking not too smart questions

Comment: @HungCaptain These aren't bad questions.  For servername, put in this verbatim: `localhost\sqlexpress`.  For login info, select Windows Authentication and then that's it.  Hit connect.